# Get due date for rental project

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a Property Rental project. For this I want to calculate due date for every month. Here is my code:

```
<?php
echo "<b>Today's Date: </b>".$Currentdate=date("d F Y");//current date
$user_date = date("d F Y",strtotime("2013-02-28"));//date you get from database

if($Currentdate<=$user_date){
    echo '<br><b>First Date : </b>'.$first_date = date("d F Y",strtotime('+2 month',strtotime($user_date)));//only if current date is less than user's date
}
else{
    echo '<br><b>Second Date : </b>'.$second_date = date("d F Y",strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $user_date ) )) ;//only if current date is more than user's date
}   
?>
```

This is good but if the user enters some previous date like today is 29th April but user enter 2nd Feb. This code will show 1st March but I want 1st May. I need the due date according to current date also. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare the formatted date.You should compare timestamp (which is an integer), so, you could keep the `strtotime()` result and compare it to `time()`:

```
echo "<b>Today's Date: </b>".$Currentdate=date("d F Y");//current date
$user_time = strtotime("2013-02-28") ;
$user_date = date("d F Y", $user_time);//date you get from database

if (time() <= $user_time){
    echo '<br><b>First Date : </b>'.$first_date = date("d F Y",strtotime('+2 month',strtotime($user_date)));//only if current date is less than user's date
}
else{
    echo '<br><b>Second Date : </b>'.$second_date = date("d F Y",strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $user_date ) )) ;//only if current date is more than user's date
}
```

Using the DateTime object (as pointed out by @Spudley), you could use [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#example-2745), and keep timestamp for all internal processing.

> As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using comparison operators.

```
$current_date = new DateTime();
$user_date = new DateTime("2013-02-02");

echo "<b>Today's Date: </b>".$current_date->format("d F Y");//current date

if ($current_date <= $user_date){
    $first_date = $user_date->modify('+2 month');
    echo '<br><b>First Date : </b>'. $first_date->format("d F Y");//only if current date is less than user's date
}
else{
    $second_date = $user_date->modify('+1 month');
    echo '<br><b>Second Date : </b>'.$second_date->format("d F Y") ;//only if current date is more than user's date
}
```

Comment: Alternative to a timestamp integer would be a `DateTime` object. Either way, use the timestamp or object for all internal processing, calculations, storage, etc, and only convert to a display format for outputting it to the screen. Same goes for input: Accept input in whatever format is necessary, but convert to timestamp or object as soon as possible and leave the input format behind.